# What could be causing a moth ball like smell?

Tags: hvac

We have a smell like moth balls in bedroom of condo. Moth balls and camphor smell coming from heating unit in bedroom.

Answer (score 1):

Given that those are **very distinctive smells**, the items mentioned are probably in the heating unit. Possibly as part of some animals's nest, if you don't have small children who might have put them there...might want to open it up and clear them out before you have a fire.